# Temporary table or View with session variables, which one to use and why?

Tags: view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, session-variables, temp-tables

I am new to Snowflake. I have a basic question. I have a large dataset that I need to use in a join with other tables.

- *Should I use a temporary table, or a view with session variables for this purpose, and why? *

fyi, its an oltp system and we will be using these things in a stored procedure (why oltp in snowflake, thats a whole different story, I do not know .)

I am inclined to using the view with session variables, as creating the temporary table might have its own additional charges. But I cannot quite justify it to my peers with solid proof. Hence need some help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Better try a few sample queries with both methods and pick one with better performance.
*temporary table might have its own additional charges*
This is correct but a temporary table can deliver better run time, especially in case of large dataset. (This will offset the storage changes with saved warehouse credits, which are more costlier compare to storage)

Comment: I don’t really understand your question. Where is this large dataset being stored now. - is it already in Snowflake? If it’s not then how would a view work (and what do you mean by a view with session variables?), if it is then why would you need a temporary table (or a view)?

Comment: Hi @NickW the dataset is already in Snowflake. We need to use it in a query, and also return that data so that it can be used in a report. 
By view with session variables, I meant reusing the view for different parameters (the view query will use these session variables). The plan was to set up different session variables for different input parameters and then fetch the corresponding data using the view.

Comment: If the data is already in Snowflake then why can't you just use it in your queries? I'm not clear why you think you need to create an additional temporary table or view in order to use this data? Can you update your question with a sample query that illustrates why you think you need these extra objects?

Comment: Hi @NickW. The data that I intend to use in the stored procedure (sp), called multiple times,is returned by a complex query (joining 4/5 tables).It has 2 uses: 1, we need to use it in a merge statement, & 2, we need to return this data from the sp. As this is a large & complex query, using it twice made the sp bulk/difficult to read & fix issues, etc. So, thought of going with a view based on the said query & some session variables (as passed via the input parameters of the sp). We can do this using temp table as well, but it may have some credit consumption due to data realignment after dml?

Comment: OK, a view is going to make it simpler to manage the process - as you only need to write the SQL once - however it is not going to help with performance. If performance is an issue then creating a table makes sense - I would look at the new dynamic tables (in public preview)

Answer (score 0):

A view with a non-transformative sub-select is no gain/loss over the raw table.

```
create table table_name(cola number, colb number);

create view table_view as select cola from table_name where colb = 5
```

but if the view is transforming the data that is used in the join, a table can help in some types of question, as the read/write happens as one step, and then for a complex or repeated use partition pruning can happen. But if view is used just once in the query, and the transform is query dependent customer id filters etc. then the view/temp both potential have to do a full read, to find the results. At which point a CTE also could be used.

Over the years we bounced back/forth Temp <-> CTE as we found our expensive queries ran better in the different forms.

Comment: Hi Simeon,  thanks for your response. there are some transformations involved in the view query. I was afraid of the extra credit usage by Snowflake to maintain metadata of the dml if we use a temporary table and insert data in that, instead of the view. 
as the view/temp table may get used multiple times (for different parameters/data ), the credit usage may build up over time and we may have to pay a lot of $.

Comment: @ARPANBANERJEE the temp table cost is the gigabytes of data in the temp table, which shows up as daily table data usage. The cost to build the table cannot be more than the SQL used to read the Stored Process as they are "the same", but it a thing where the is no hard and fast rule. Both methods cost "more than the other would" if you use them like they are the other.